# How can I extract substring from the given url using regex in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, regex, android-studio

I'm trying to extract `CANseIqFMnf` from the URL `https://www.instagram.com/p/CANseIqFMnf/` using regex in Android studio. Please help me to get a regex expression eligible for Android Studio.

Here is the code for my method:

```
String url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CANseIqFMnf/";
    String REGEX = "/p\//";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

    boolean match = matcher.matches();

    if (match){
        Log.e("success", "start = " + matcher.start() + " end = " + matcher.end() );
    }else{
        Log.e("failed", "failed");
    }
```

But it gives me failed in return!

Comment: Experiment at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html. And consider whether it would be simpler to parse the URL (e.g., as a `Uri`) and get the last path segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1

You just need to use `replaceAll` method in `String`, no need to compile a pattern and complicate things:

```
String input = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CANseIqFMnf/";
String output = input.replaceAll("https://www.instagram.com/p/", "").replaceAll("/", "");
Log.v(TAG, output);
```

Note that the first `replaceAll` is to remove the `url` and the second `replaceAll` is to remove any slashes `/`

#### Method 2

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https://www.instagram.com/p/(.*?)/");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("https://www.instagram.com/p/CANseIqFMnf/");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Note that if `matcher.find()` returns `true` then if you used modifiers like this in your REGEX `(.*?)` then the part found there will be in `group(1)`, and `group(0)` will hold the entire regex match which is in your case the entire url.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option w/o regex can be implemented in a simpler manner as below using `java.nio.file.Paths` APIs

```
public class Url {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CANseIqFMnf/";
        String name = java.nio.file.Paths.get(url).getFileName().toString();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```